# NHAML Radio Button Syntax

Tags: button, radio-button, nhaml

Does anyone know the correct syntax for a selected radio button in NHAML?

This is my current NHAML code: %input{type="radio", name="Relocation", value="Yes"}

The help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of NHaml ([2.0 Beta 2](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/)) changes the way it handles attributes. Don't use commas:

```
%input{type="radio" name="Relocation" value="Yes"}
```

Answer (score 1):

NHaml 2.0 Beta 1 syntax

```
%input{type="radio", name="Relocation", checked="true"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%input {type="radio" name="Relocation" checked="checked" value="TrueOrWhatever"}
```

OR just use HtmlHelper